# When doing Select Device in Android Studio or VSCode in Flutter, Failed to launch INFO | An error message saying “Storing crashdata in:” appears

Tags: android, flutter, dart, android-studio

An error message appears when using SelectDevice in VSCode or Android Studio.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DpGlV.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TGinA.png)

When I press Select Device in VSCode, an error like this appears,

Failed to launch INFO | Storing crashdata in: /tmp/android-moongibae/emu-crash-34.1.19.db, detection is enabled for process: 67546: emulator 'INFO | Storing crashdata in: /tmp/android-moongibae/emu-crash-34.1.19.db, detection is enabled for process: 67546' not found

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YwGTx.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GdKgc.png)

When you press Select Device on Android, an error occurs like this.

ERROR | Unknown AVD name [INFO | Storing crashdata in: /tmp/android-moongibae/emu-crash-34.1.19.db, detection is enabled for process: 67611], use -list-avds to see valid list. INFO | Storing crashdata in: /tmp/android-moongibae/emu-crash-34.1.19.db, detection is enabled for process: 68319 ERROR | HOME is defined but there is no file INFO | Storing crashdata in: /tmp/android-moongibae/emu-crash-34.1.19.db, detection is enabled for process: 67611.ini in $HOME/.android/avd ERROR | (Note: Directories are searched in the order $ANDROID_AVD_HOME, $ANDROID_SDK_HOME/avd and $HOME/.android/avd) INFO | Android emulator version 34.1.19.0 (build_id 11525734) (CL:N/A)

I tried the following to solve this problem, but I still get the error:

1. Even after uninstalling VSCode and not logging in, the issue persists.
2. Removing Android Studio eliminates the INFO message.
3. Despite reinstalling the operating system and even resetting all settings, the INFO message remains.
4. Even with just the operating system reinstalled and only VSCode, Android Studio, and Xcode installed while logged in with only the Apple ID, the INFO message persists.
5. Trying with different projects yields the same INFO message.
6. The issue persists even when pressing "Wife Data" in Android Studio.
7. Suspecting a version issue, I tried installing older versions, but the INFO crash data still